# Camunda: how i can get all completed tasks by processInstanceId

Tags: java, camunda, tasklist

I use `camunda_bpm_api` and i need get all completed user tasks for process instance.

If I use:

```
List<Task> result  = taskService.createTaskQuery().processInstanceId(historicProcessInstances.get(i).getId()).list()
```

i get last user task.

How i can get all completed user tasks?

Answer (score 2):

To get completed tasks, you have to query against the history:

```
historyService.createHistoricTaskInstanceQuery()
   ...
   .list();
```